# Convolution of 2D Gauss with Cylinder in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, 2d, gaussian, convolution

I want to convolute a 2D Gaussian with a cylinder function in Mathematica. Mathematica will however just create an empty function without error messages (i.e. it behaves normally), thus when plotting the function or using it for calculations, nothing happens at all. Here is the 2D Gauss:

```
GaussFkt2D[x_, y_, mux_, muy_, sigmax_, sigmay_, A_] :=
A*E^-((x - mux)^2/(2 sigmax^2) + (y - muy)^2/(2 sigmay^2))
```

And here is the cylinder function:

```
cylFkt2D[x_, y_, w_] := 
Piecewise[{{0, x^2 + y^2 > (w)^2}, {1, x^2 + y^2 <= (w)^2}}]
```

To convolute, I use:

```
ConvolutionCylinderGauss2D[u_, v_, mux_, muy_, sigmax_, sigmay_, A_,w_] =
Convolve[
         GaussFkt2D[x, y, mux, muy, sigmax, sigmay, A], 
         cylFkt2D[x, y, w], {x, y}, {u, v}
        ];
```

Is there a possibility to implement the convolution in such a way that Mathematica will not spoil the convolution? I suppose the problem could be that Mathematica is just overloaded when doing the convolution.

Comment: What do you mean "spoil the convolution" ?

Comment: I mean that the convolution yields a function which I can at least plot and will not give me a void plot.